# How can I explain quitting my job because my boss lied in order to put me on probation?

Tags: applications

I'd been with this large organization for almost 24 years. I had been at this location almost 6 years when we received a new supervisor. Big changes began to happen; there was no support, no positive feedback, ever! Other staff noticed her negative attitude towards me.

My breaking point came when she decides to do an evaluation on me (out the blue) **2 days before all staff were to receive a one-time bonus**. Which now I can't receive because she lied & scored me so low I'm put on probation!! We don't get raises so the bonus was a really big deal! I gave my 2 week notice.

***I need to know how to address my termination during interviews. I know a potential employer will question why I left after so many years.*** I wouldn't ever speak ill of this person. I had loved my job and the fast-paced, stressful & challenging atmosphere. Thanks!

Comment: Daphine: Unfortunately, this question is indeed off-topic, but @Kate Gregory responded with an awesome answer and Jenny D has an awesome comment. All in all, I don't think this incident will impair your ability to find a new job. Good luck!

Answer (score 27):

Don't overthink this. You were in a job for decades. Now you are looking for a new job. Why? Because you are ready for new challenges? Because you want to work less (or more) now that you are in a different phase of your life? Because you've always wanted to work in a particular field, or kind of company? Because you were just ready for a change?

That's what employers want to hear. What you want now and what you're doing about that. Not a long story (or even a single sentence) about how your old boss ruined everything. If someone pushes very hard on "why would you leave your old position after so long?" you can say "companies change over time, and some of the changes at [old place] meant that it wasn't right for me any more." Then turn the focus back to what you are looking for and why the job you're interviewing for is a great fit for you.

Comment: +many. Trim down the answer just as folks have suggested you might trim down the question: Cut out all the irrelevancies, put it in capsule form that dodges the whole blame issue, and focus the interview back on what you want them to remember.

Comment: I'd like to put a lot of emphasis on **not mentioning that your boss ruined everything**. It doesn't matter that it's actually true, it will still come across as you badmouthing them and it will make a potential employer think you're going to not be a good member of the team. In fact, as a general rule, don't say anything bad about current or previous employers or coworkers at all while you're in a professional setting. If you can't be positive, avoid the topic - people will then understand that you don't like them and you'll get credit for being a good person.